# How to install matplotlib on python3.4 raspberry pi

Tags: python, matplotlib, raspberry-pi, pip, python-3.4

I am trying to install matplotlib on python3.4 (the default version on raspberry pi) via pip3 but the installation always fails.

I have tried installing python3.7 but pip3 defaults to installing on python3.4 and I don't know how to change that.

The error message I constantly get is " Beginning with Matplotlib 3.1, Python 3.6 or above is required.". How do I update my python on the pi or install it on python3.4?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried to install it via apt ? `sudo apt-get install python3-matplotlib` The dependencies should be OK there.

Answer (score 1):

Having just looked at older releases ( https://pypi.org/project/matplotlib/#history ), I think 2.2.4 was the last version to work on Python 3.4
You can install a specific version of the library using the command

```
pip install matplotlib==2.2.4
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the package manager of the distribution :

```
sudo apt install python3-matplotlib
```

The dependencies should be OK there.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use

```
sudo pip3 install matplotlib
```

or for a local instlal of the lib

```
pip3 install --user <your_username> matplotlib
```